# Handle data and a php loop in JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have this college problem, but I can't solve it at all, no matter how hard I try.

The problem consists of handling data from a loop in php using javascript. I have to show only the value that was selected in a select, and show how many times the value is repeated in the other select. follow the code below:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script language="javascript">
        function setorSelected(){
            var setorSelect = document.getElementById("setor").value;
            var resultado = document.getElementById("result").value;
            document.getElementById("mostrar").style.display ="inline";
            if(setorSelect == resultado){
                document.getElementById("ocultar").style.display ="none";

            }
        }
        </script>
    
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
        <label class="col-sm-12 col-form-label">SETOR</label>
        <select onchange="setorSelected()" name="rand" id="setor"  class="form-select" aria-label="Selecione" required>
            <option value="">Selecione..</option>
        <?php
            $total = 5;
            for($i=0;$i<=$total;$i++){
        ?>
            <option
            value="<?php echo $i;?>">
            <?php echo $i;?> 
            </option>


            <?php

        }
        ?>
        </select>
        </div >
        <p></p>
            
        <div style="display:none" id="mostrar">
        <label class="col-sm-12 col-form-label">RESULTADO</label>
        <select name="rand" id="result"  class="form-select" aria-label="Selecione" required>
            <option value="">Selecione..</option>
        <?php

            $total = 20;
            $setor = 2;
            for($i=0;$i<=$total;$i++){
        ?>
            <option 
            style="display:inline;"
            id="ocultar"
            value="<?php echo rand(1,5);?>">
            <?php echo rand(1,5);?>  
            </option>


            <?php

        }
        ?>
        </select>
        </div>
       
    </body>
```

i used this function onchange="setorSelected()" to call it in javaScript, but the problem is that the comparison inside the javascript sectorSelect == result is not treating the option data of the second select

Comment: Not sure what you'd want with `style="display:inline;"` on an option. `id="ocultar"` is an error in any case - you have this in a loop, but IDs must be unique. You can not expect getElementById to work correctly with that, it will only ever find the first element with that ID.

Comment: yes, I have an idea that the IDS must be unique, but I don't know how to pass this to javascript

Comment: This should not use IDs for that to begin with. Loop over all the options of the second select instead. In the loop, check if the value matches that in `setorSelect`, and depending on that either show or hide the current option.

Comment: the php process when the page is loaded, and I want to change the second select dynamically according to what was selected in the first select, however the id must be treated uniquely as you said, and I still haven't found one way of sending to handle one by one

Comment: if you had a forum that has a similar example, I really appreciate it

Comment: _"and I still haven't found one way of sending to handle one by one"_ - not sure what that is even supposed to mean. _"and I want to change the second select dynamically"_ - you simply want to show or hide the options, which have random values, based on whether their value matches the selection from the first select field, yes? Well then do that as I said - _loop over_ the options of the second select. You don't need _any_ IDs on the options to do that.